# Javascript variable not define inside function

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript based life game, and I am trying to make a balance system for it. When I click on my button that calls my function balance(), an error occurs where the console fails to find my defined variable. Please help here is my code:

```js
var balance;

function balance() {
  let newbalance = balance + 100;
  let balance = newbalance;
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = (balance);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Malar" rel="stylesheet">
<center>
  <h1 class="title">Life Game</h1>
</center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="mainTd">
      <h1 id="balance">0</h1>
    </td>
    <td class="mainTd">
      <h1 id="state">Begger</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="balance()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Please show the minimal HTML this operates on.

Comment: How is the error message you're getting leaving anything unclear? `"message": "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'balance' before initialization"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three issues.

## not initializing the balance variable

if you had not other issues, the code would still not work. you create a variable `balance` without setting the variable thus it will be `undefined`. Thus adding 100 to it will result in a `NaN`

```
> var balance
undefined
> balance + 100
NaN
```

## re-assigning the balance variable

At first you define a global uninitialised variable `balance` for storing the balance value. Then you define function `balance` which will be assigned to the same variable. Thus the variable `balance` will point to a function from now on.

```
> var balance;
undefined
> balance
undefined
> function balance() {}
undefined
> balance
[Function: balance]
```

## shadowing the balance variable

Inside a the function you define a block scoped(`let`) variable `balance`. This will be a completely new variable that exists only inside of the function, thus anything you do to it would not affect the `balance` variable outside of the function. This is called shadowing and linters should warn about this.

```
> var balance = 11;
undefined
> function calc() {
... let balance = 22;
... return balance;
... }
undefined
> balance
11
> calc()
22
> balance 
11 <- original balance is still the same
```

## fixed code

```js
var balance = 0; // set initial value

function calculateBalance() { // use unique name for function
  let newbalance = balance + 100;
  balance = newbalance; // use the global variable instead of defining a new one 
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = (balance);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Malar" rel="stylesheet">
<center>
  <h1 class="title">Life Game</h1>
</center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="mainTd">
      <h1 id="balance">0</h1>
    </td>
    <td class="mainTd">
      <h1 id="state">Begger</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="calculateBalance()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have named your function `balance` which is shadowing the variable outside.

after changing the name of function give some default value to balance , 
`var balance = 0;`

Comment: give default value to answer, its adding to undefined

Comment: You also need to rename the local `balance` variable inside your function. You have a temporal dead zone before the line `let balance = `.